# Time-series decomposition error using stldecompose with Tz-aware datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I want to decompose a monthly time-series using `STLdecompose`.
This is part of my data.

```
DateTime    PR
0   2011-02-28 00:00:00+01:00   0.868726
1   2011-03-31 00:00:00+02:00   0.860876
2   2011-04-30 00:00:00+02:00   0.825224
3   2011-05-31 00:00:00+02:00   0.817706
4   2011-06-30 00:00:00+02:00   0.806191
```

As shown DateTime is a Tz-aware datetime. The timezone is `Europe/Rome`.
When using `decomp = decompose(obs, period=12)`, it returns `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'`.
Any idea how to solve it? Thanks for your help.